# Excursion inside British Rail Class 55 "Deltic"

Tags: uk, trains

I really like the train called British Rail Class 55 "Deltic", but I've never seen it for real and would like to visit the UK and see it.

Are there any excursions inside that train? And if yes, how to visit it?

I've found that trains ride sometimes, but cannot find a timetable for such rides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only can you visit one of these "Deltic", but you can even drive the locomotives.

First you can find about the [6 locomotives that were preserved](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_Class_55#Preservation). It happens to [have many fans](HTTP://www.royalscotsgrey.com) and many events are organised, the fan site lists these events.

Some of these events include [driving these locomotives](HTTP://www.nvr.org.uk/driver-experience). This website says that you need to be over 18 and physically fit in order to drive one, no other conditions is required. The last one was in October, you can follow the website to find out when the next event happens. This is not regularly organised but there will probably be some more in the future.

Comment: The Nene Valley Railway does not permanently have a Deltic, the only three mainline registered ones are all owned by other operators - while the NVR had a Deltic tour in 2016 there is no guarantee at all they will have one in 2017.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you keep an eye on the [Deltic Preservation Society](http://thedps.co.uk/) website, which tracks the Deltic tours.

Doesn't look like any 2017 dates have been announced yet, but as there were Deltics active in 2016 you may be lucky.